# Use docker compose config from file and stdin

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose can use a config file from stdin using `-f -` (Example: `cat config.yml | docker-compose -f - up`)

However, this does not seem to work when providing multiple config files. For example, the command:

```
cat config.yml | docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml -f - up
```

returns with the error: `ERROR: .FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './-'`

Is there a way to use multiple config files and still provide one config through stdin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the special device `/dev/stdin`, as in:

```
cat config.yml | docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f /dev/stdin up
```

This may not work in all cases (I've encountered some oddness when `-f /dev/stdin` is the first file listed on the command line), but it does seem to work.